# Extract vertical planes from Point cloud

Tags: point-cloud, feature-extraction, ransac

I am looking for a tool/method for extraction of vertical planes (building facades, fences, ...) from mobile mapping point clouds.

There is software (Cloud compare e.g.) that offers RANSAC plane detection, which works not bad after tweaking parameters, but the planes are rectangles, there is no option for cutting the plane along the convex hull (or alpha shape?) of the facade.

Is there a tool that can handle the sectioning/cutting of the rectangular plane?